# Union of two $\sigma$-algebras is not $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Here is another very basic analysis problem but that puzzles me:

> Find an example of set $X$ and its two $\sigma$-algebras $\mathscr A_1$ and $\mathscr A_2$, such that $\mathscr A_1 \cup \mathscr A_2$ is not $\sigma$-algebra.

To me at least, this question looks counter-intuitive since the union of two sets gives the resulting set larger number of elements, thus won't affect its $\sigma$-algebra status.

Please help and thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: The problem becomes much harder if we change it to be: "Find an example that the union of two sigma algebras is an algebra but not a sigma algebra."

Answer (score 33, accepted):

take $X := \{a,b,c\}$ and $A_1 := \{ \{a\}, \{b,c\}, \emptyset, X\}$, $A_2 := \{ \{b\}, \{a,c\}, \emptyset, X\}$ and show that $A_1 \cup A_2$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra

Comment: Thanks & I like your solution. But forgive my slowpoke mind, I didn't see it fails the conditions. $X$ and $\emptyset$ are there, all complements are there, the union of all is the $X$, and the intersection of all is there, $\{a\} \cap \{b, c\} \cap \{b\} \cap\ \{a, c\} = \emptyset$. I am sure I missed something. What is that?

Comment: @A.Magnus $\{a\}\cup\{b\}=\{a,b\}$ is not there.

Comment: @drhab : When we talk about the union (or intersection) of elements in the conditions, is that union (or intersection) of two elements at a time? Or all elements together? Because if it's about all elements together at the same time, then $\{a\}\cup \{b,c\}\cup\{b\}\cup \{a,c\}=\{a, b, c\}$, which is $X$. Did I miss again?

Comment: Let $\mathcal A:=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{b,c\},\{a,c\},X\}$ i.e. the union of the two sigma-algebras mentioned in this answer. If $\mathcal A$ would be a sigma-algebra (wich is not the case) then it should satisfy: if $A_n\in\mathcal A$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\in\mathcal A$. However, if we take $A_n=\{a\}$ for $n$ even and $A_n=\{b\}$ for $n$ odd then we get $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\{a,b\}\notin\mathcal A$.

Comment: @drhab : So am I wrong if I write like these: $\bigcup_{n=1}^{6} :=  A_1 \cup  A_2 \cup  A_3 \cup\  A_4 \cup  A_5 \cup  A_6 = \emptyset \cup \{a\} \cup \{b\} \cup \{b,c\} \cup \{a,c\} \cup X = X$? Do let me know & thanks.

Comment: If you like you can write $A_1=\emptyset$, $A_2=\{a\}$ et cetera and come to the conclusion that $\bigcup_{n=1}^6 A_n=X$ (nothing against it), but what has that to do with checking whether we are dealing here with a sigma-algebra? Nothing! For this you must check what I mentioned in my former comment (and also it must be checked to be closed under complements, wich is the case here).

Comment: I think I misunderstood from the beginning the textbook's 4th. condition in $\sigma$-algebra: "Whenever $A_1, A_2, \ldots $ are in $\mathscr A$, then $\bigcup _{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ and $\bigcap _{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ are in $\mathscr A$." So here $\infty$ should be read as "any number." I said this because in another posting I saw that this condiution should be read "...for any sequence $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb ℕ}$ of elements in a $\sigma$-algebra, the union $⋃_{i \in \mathbb ℕ}X_i$ is in $\mathscr A$." Sorry for this long debate! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

$\{\emptyset,[0,3/4),[3/4,1),[0,1)\}$ and $\{\emptyset,[0,1/2),[1/2,1),[0,1)\}$ are $\sigma-$algebras but their union $\{\emptyset,[0,3/4),[3/4,1),[0,1/2),[1/2,1),[0,1)\}$ is not. $[0,3/4)\ minus \ [1/2,1)=[1/2,3/4)$ is not in the union.

Answer (score 3):

Let it be that $X=A\cup B=U\cup V$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset=U\cap V$.
Then $\mathcal{A}=\left\{ \emptyset,A,B,X\right\} $ and $\mathcal{V}=\left\{ \emptyset,U,V,X\right\} $
are both $\sigma$-algebras. Is $\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{V}$ a $\sigma$-algebra?

Not if $A\cup U\notin\mathcal{A}$ and $A\cup U\notin\mathcal{V}$.