# Is $\mathcal{F}_\infty$ a $\sigma$-algebra? (Chung Theorem 9.4.8.)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, filtrations

We let $\mathcal{F}_\infty=\bigvee_n\mathcal{F}_n$. (What does $\bigvee$ usually denote? Is $\bigvee$ different from $\cup$? Can't find it in the text.)

The theorem tells us when we have $\lim_n E(Y|\mathcal{F}_n)=E(Y|\mathcal{F}_\infty)$.

I'd like to know:

- Is $\mathcal{F}_\infty$ a $\sigma$-algebra?
- Is it true that $A\in\mathcal{F}_\infty$ implies $A\in\mathcal{F}_n$ for some $n$?

It seems the answer to the former (assuming the latter is true) is no: If $A\in \mathcal{F}_1$ and $B\in\mathcal{F}_2$, then $A\cup B$ need not be an element of $\mathcal{F_n}$ for any $n$.

But then $E(Y|\mathcal{F}_\infty)$ is nonsensical, since conditional expectation (as a random variable) is defined using $\sigma$-algebras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\bigvee_n \mathcal{F}_n$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\bigcup_n \mathcal{F}_n$ (i.e., smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\bigcup_n \mathcal{F}_n$).

This is needed because in general, $\bigcup_n \mathcal{F}_n$ might not be a $\sigma$-algebra.
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122081/union-of-two-sigma-algebras-is-not-sigma-algebra) for an easy example.
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5119/example-where-union-of-increasing-sigma-algebras-is-not-a-sigma-algebra) for an example where the sequence is nested, i.e. $\mathcal{F}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{F}_2 \subseteq \cdots$.

So, by definition $\mathcal{F}_\infty$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. For your second bullet-point, I think the answer is no.

Comment: Bummer. I'd like to see why we have $\int_A Y=\int_A X_n=\int_A X_\infty$, where $A\in\mathcal{F}_\infty$. This is clear when $A\in\mathcal{F}_\infty$ implies $A\in\mathcal{F}_n$ for some $n$ (i.e. second bullet point is true). Not sure otherwise. Any pointers?

Comment: @manofbear: Your comment seems to involve a lot of additional context, so you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the tip, will do